# PHP: change time format 15:30:00 to 3:30PM

Tags: php, date, time

I have a little issue with php and the time format.
I tried to change the time using the date() function.

```
$time = date('g:i a',$time);
```

But the result I get for `$time=15:30:30` is `3:30 am`

The Ante meridiem stay stuck on AM event if it's the afternoon.

Thanks.

Comment: You literally use `date('g:i a', '15:30:00')`? If so I'm surprised you get any result at all.

Comment: It's `date($format, $unixtimestamp);`, so setting `$unixtimestamp` to `"15:30:30"` would not work the way you want it to.

Comment: I first enter a time in my database using the TIME type. So literally in PHPmyadmin I can read 15:30:00. So the $time variable is set with the information get from the Database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 $time = date("g:i a", strtotime("15:30:00"));
```

Comment: Same result. :( I still get 3:30 am

Comment: I'm testing it and I get "3:30 pm"

Comment: Ok I'm a little bit ashamed on this one. I made a mistake somewhere else so my variable $time was wrong from the beginning. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

If taken from database
My past codes were

```
// get the Shift times
$shiftArray=array();
$num=0;


 $getShiftTimes=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM shift");

 while ($returnShiftTimes = mysqli_fetch_array($getShiftTimes)){
      $shiftArray[$num][0]=$returnShiftTimes['shift_id'];
      $shiftArray[$num][1]=$returnShiftTimes['start_time'];
      $shiftArray[$num][2]=$returnShiftTimes['end_time'];
      $num++;
 }

 $time = date_format(date_create($shiftArray[0][1]), 'g:i A');
```

From 14:00:00 will return 2:00 PM